# Why is the content after the zero character not assigned?

Tags: c++, string

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    string a;
    a="this is string\0 this part not assigned why?";
    cout<<a;
    cout<<"sth";
cout<<endl;
    a.push_back('\0');
        cout<<a;
        cout<<"sth";
}
```

Q: Why is the content after the `\0` not assigned to the string `a`?

Comment: that is not a newline character

Comment: @tobi303 thanks for correcting that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are [assigning](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%3D) the value of a null terminated [string literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) to your `std::string` variable. The string literal gets *cut off* at the null terminator `\0` because it is of type `const char[]` so the resulting string is:

> `this is string`

If you want to keep the entire string then use the string's  [operator""s](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s), add the `s` suffix and compile with the C++14 support enabled. This will form a string literal of type `std::string`:

```
std::string a = "this is string\0 this part not assigned why?"s;
std::cout << a;
```

The result is now:

> `this is string this part not assigned why?`

The [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) states (emphasis mine):

> Initialization with a string literal that contains embedded '\0'
>   characters uses the overload (5), which **stops** at the first null
>   character. This can be avoided by specifying a different constructor
>   or by using **operator""s**:

Comment: can you explain more about the 's' suffix

Comment: Note the *assignment operator* is called the way the OP has it. In your case, yes, the constructor is called.

Answer (score 2):

In C++, **C-style strings are terminated by a zero character**.

This code:

```
a = "this is string\0 this part not assigned why?";
```

You're calling the function `string& string::operator =(const char*)`, which **determines the end of string by an occurrence of a zero**. Of course it thinks the string is over when it sees `\0`.

FYR, if you want a newline character, use `\n` instead of a zero character.

Comment: i intented to write \0 not a newline character. You can edit that accordingly

Answer (score 2):

The expression `a = "this is string\0 this part not assigned why?"` is using the `std::string` assignment operator takes a `const char*` as an argument. (The `const char[]` literal decays to a `const char*`.)

That operator is defined to stop reading when it encounters the first NUL-terminator. In your case, that will be the explicit `\0` in the input literal, not the implicit one at the end.

Comment: No, `a` is default-constructed in the line above.

Answer (score 1):

C and C++(for c-style strings) mark end of string with `'\0'` character. Suppose `"hi"` as an string. It contains three characters i.e `h`, `i` and `\0` actually.

Comment: i dont think c++ marks the end of string with \0 character , i think its only for C style strings

Answer (score 1):

To use the entire string literal as the value of the string variable, you can pass in the length of the string literal.  That can include the explicit and implicit `'\0'` characters as well.

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

template<typename T, std::size_t size>
std::size_t GetArrayLength(T(&)[size]){
  return size;
}

int main() {
  string a;
  char const s[] = "this is a string\0 this part not assigned why?";
  a = string{s, GetArrayLength(s)};
  cout << a << endl;
  for (auto c : a) {
    if (c >= ' ' && c <= '~')
      cout << c;
    else
      cout << "<" << (int)c << ">";
  }
  cout << endl;
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`’\0’` denotes the end of a string, so any characters coming behind it are not considered a part of the string by most functions, including `cout`.

Consider that these functions need to have a way to know how far to go in the string (otherwise they would continue through all the memory), and th `’\0’` is the agreed-upon end-marker.

If you want a newline, use `’\n’`.

Comment: C++ `std::string`s can contain `\0` and `cout` will consider it part of the string. The issue is with C strings.

Comment: what interjay said is also verified by the second cout statement